# C++: How to find out which symbol I forgot to explicitly set to default visibility in my visibility=hidden library?

Tags: c++, linker, segmentation-fault, visibility

I'm developing a C++ library in Linux with gcc, which I'm compiling with visibility=hidden. (I think) I have explicitly marked the different functions and classes that can be used by the user of the library to default visibility using
`__attribute__((__visibility__("default")))`

I'm now writing a program that uses this library and I'm running into weird runtime segfaults. The stack trace does not give a clear indication what is going on, but upon recompiling my library with default visibility, everything works fine.

Hence my theory is that I forgot to explicitly set some class or other symbol to default visibility and that my segfault is being caused by this.

As mentioned before, debugging with gdb doesn't give me a clear indication which symbol might be causing the problem. Is there another smart way to find out what is going wrong? (Do automated checkers/verification tools exists for this kind of stuff?)

Comment: Could have to do with RTTI and typeinfo.  If that is being used, and it is hidden, it can cause ODR violation, which can lead to undefined behavior.  The undefined behavior may be exhibiting as a segfault.  Pure speculation, though, without a [mcve].

Comment: I was indeed thinking it would be something along those lines. If I could make a minimal reproducible example, I would probably be able to solve it as well :P. My unit test don't exhibit the behavior and trying to home in on the part of the code that produces the problems is quite hard (it seems that the call where it segfaults is unrelated to the root cause of the problem). This is why I was hoping that there was some automated checker that checks the required symbols against the provided symbols

Comment: For my project, we don't use `visibility=hidden` because it causes all sorts of problems with C++ (except for the libraries that have a strictly C ABI interface, with opaque pointers and no consumer facing object-oriented facilities).  Instead, we use `namespace Component { namespace detail {` to hide details in the detail inner namespace of the outward facing component.